# Why doesn't javascript_include_tag reference work?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In a new Rails app, it will have the following tag, which includes all js files in the javascripts folder:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application'%>
```

It also creates odd looking references to those js files at run-time:

```
<script src="/assets/cbpAnimatedHeader.self-2f56b42e64e4cd1aeca79d75fab98d1e72c4ee686ded129c7b6bd100065c0c84.js?body=1"></script>
```

When I use functions on the page that come from the above file, I get a not found error.

If I instead add this reference, everything works fine:

```
<script src="assets/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>
```

Why doesn't the javascript_include_tag reference work?

Comment: Show the inclusion in your application.js file. Everything normal? Is this for production?

Comment: What do you mean by show the inclusion?  This is for development.

Comment: `application.js` is including the `cbpAnimatedHeader.js` file (should be, anyway)

Comment: I don't have anything in application.js.

Comment: Where are you including `cbpAnimatedHeader.js`? Your `javascript_include_tag` shows "application"

Comment: All the OP code is coming from application.html.erb.

Answer (score 1):

**In development** when you add assets to the Sprockets manifest like so:

```
// app/assets/javascripts/foo.js
//= require bar
//= require baz
```

And the use the Rails asset helpers:

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "foo" %>
```

Rails will create a script tag for `foo.js` and one for `bar` and `baz`. Attached the file name is a digest - this is a checksum which is used as a cache buster mechanism so you don't have to deal with browser cache issues in production.

By using individual script tags it is easier to troubleshoot since you get a line number in the individual file - not in a concatenated file*.

**In production** you would either compile the assets before deploying or set up a post commit hook which does the same. The latter is usually much less human error prone and generates less noise in the git history.

When compiling Rails will concatenate `bar` and `baz` into `foo.js`. 
`<%= javascript_include_tag "foo" %>` creates a single script tag with `foo.js` - again a digest is included as a cache busting mechanism.

### So why am I getting undefined errors?

This is most likely cause is improper ordering - if your scripts has dependencies which must be available before hand you should not rely on `//= require_tree .` to load it!

Instead you would do something like:

```
//= require 'cbpAnimatedHeader'
//= require_tree .
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Answer (score 1):

> odd looking references at run-time

They are the [`fingerprints` of the asset file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark):

*Fingerprinting is a technique that makes the name of a file dependent on the contents of the file. When the file contents change, the filename is also changed. For content that is static or infrequently changed, this provides an easy way to tell whether two versions of a file are identical, even across different servers or deployment dates.*

It's a standard part of Rails functionality - especially apparent when you *precompile* your assets & run them in production.

--

> Why doesn't the `javascript_include_tag` reference work?

It probably does...

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application'%>
```

This calls `app/assets/application.js`. Whilst not a problem, it means you have to ensure you've included all your `js` files with the [`sprockets manifest directives`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
// ...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

It must be noted the above looks in the `app/assets/javascripts` folder (it seems your `cbpAnimatedHeader.js` is in `app/assets`.

The above should work, considering you have `app/assets/javascripts/cbpAnimatedHeader.js`